# Get coordinates of a building with geocoding

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, java, geocoding, android

I want to get the coordinates of a building with geocoding. At the moment I use the GeoCoder class for android to get from the selected address the coordinates, but these are not corresponding to the edge of the building. OSM is containing these information for each building, but I do not know how to get these information with the GeoCoder class. Is there a possibility to use OSM with the geocoder class for android to get this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can only use geocoders included with the Android platform when using the [Android Geocoder class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html).  In other words, you can't add a custom geocoder to Android as a user of the device.  And, to my knowledge, no Android implementations on commercial devices include OpenStreetMap data.

An alternative is to use something like [MapQuest's Nominatum REST API](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/nominatim), which is one options we're using in our [OpenTripPlanner for Android](https://github.com/CUTR-at-USF/OpenTripPlanner-for-Android/wiki) mobile app.  Here's the [source code](https://github.com/CUTR-at-USF/OpenTripPlanner-for-Android/blob/master/src/edu/usf/cutr/opentripplanner/android/tasks/OTPGeocoding.java) for the Geocoding options in OTP Android (which also includes [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) client code, but Google Places won't get you OSM data).

No matter which geocoder you use, though, you're not likely to get a building latitude and longitude from a street address.  Instead, you'll likely get a lat/long on the street network, which is what you're seeing from Android's geocoder now.  Addresses are inherently tied to the streets, which are typically offset from the actual physical building location by a fair distance.  Also be aware that some geocoders will interpolate lat/longs from a street address based on the first and last address of the block.  This behavior will give you even less accurate information, since the location on the street might not even be "in front" of the physical location of the building.